# Can a Ruby script tell what directory it’s in?

Tags: ruby, scripting, path, directory, environment-variables

Inspired by "[Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-which-directory-it-is-stored-in)", what's the Ruby way to do this?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

For newer versions of Ruby, try:

- `__dir__`

For older versions of Ruby (< 2.0), the script being run can be found using:

- `File.dirname(__FILE__)` - relative path; or
- `File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))` - the absolute path.

***Note:** Using `__dir__` will return the script path even after a call to `Dir.chdir`; whereas, using the older syntax may not return the path to the script.*

Comment: The 'File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))' was useful in finding trhe absolute path

Answer (score 89):

## Use `__dir__`

As of Ruby 2.0, `__dir__` is the simplest way to get this. It

> Returns the canonicalized absolute path of the directory of the file
>   from which this method is called.

See the [`__dir__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__) documentation, and "[Why is __FILE__ uppercase and __dir__ lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190700/why-is-file-uppercase-and-dir-lowercase)".

Comment: Well, aside from `__dir__` being the correct answer, thanks for also linking to the uppercase-vs-lowercase difference, was my first question after finding it as well :)

Answer (score 11):

use [`__dir__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__)

`File.dirname(__FILE__)` is not a proper way to get directory where script is stored.

At start working directory and directory with script file is the same, but it may change.

For example:

```
Dir.chdir('..') do
    puts __dir__
    puts File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
end
```

for script file stored in `/Desktop/tmp` running it will give output

```
/home/mateusz/Desktop/tmp
/home/mateusz/Desktop
```

Answer (score -10):

ENV["PWD"] seems the simplest way for me under Linux.   I don't know of an OS-agnostic way.

Comment: Thanks! Good for my Linux-specific general knowledge.

Comment: That's the home directory, not the current working directory or the directory where the script is located.

Comment: B*gger, lack of sleep will do that.  I meant ENV["PWD"] of course.  But ba's answer is way better.

Comment: Isn't that simply the working directory of the process?  I thought that the OP wanted the directory containing the script.

Comment: No, the process could execute an external script from elsewhere.

Comment: This env var depends on the shell. It's nowhere near "reliable". E.g., services forked off `systemd` doesn't contain this variable at all.