# How to find the full path that was used to run a Ruby script

Tags: ruby, path

I have a script ("foo") that gets installed as an executable command on the path.  I can invoke `foo` on the commandline to get the currently installed version.

But sometimes I like to run a development version by running `path/to/script/home/foo`.

Is there a way that I can tell if `foo` was invoked by calling `foo` or if it was called using the full path?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206714/can-a-ruby-script-tell-what-directory-it-s-in for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access that value as `$0` inside your script.

Comment: Works great.  Thank you!