# How get Xcode project root folder path in ruby script file?

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode

I am trying to write Xcode project run script in ruby. The script file will saved in ruby file(with `.rb` extension) in the Xcode project root folder. I am using this command

`ruby ${SRCROOT}/Path/ruby_script_file_name.rb`

for running the script on building project.
I need to get Xcode project root folder path in the ruby script file as variable.

How can I get Xcode project root folder path in ruby script file?

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer:
For getting root path I can user current ruby script folder path:
`__dir__`

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2206731/3275012

Comment: Seems rather fragile. The correct approach is to use the Ruby version of the environment variable you already referenced, `${SRCROOT}`. The Ruby way to reference that is `ENV["SRCROOT"]`.

Comment: Thank you @matt. Your suggestion is worked.